# Batch Script Programming -- How to allow a user to select a file by number from a list of files in a folder?

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop, directory, user-input

I have a folder with N files in it. I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

Display a list of the files with numbers next to them for selection:

```
01 - FileA.pdf
02 - FileB.pdf
03 - FileC.pdf
...
```

Then, have the user select which file he wants to use by typing in the corresponding number. I have no idea where to even begin with this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following batch script should do what you want, the explanation follows below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET index=1

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   SET file!index!=%%f
   ECHO !index! - %%f
   SET /A index=!index!+1
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /P selection="select file by number:"

SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO invalid number selected   
   EXIT /B 1
)

CALL :RESOLVE %%file%selection%%%

ECHO selected file name: %file_name%

GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET file_name=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

First of all this script uses something like an array to store the file names. This array is filled in the `FOR`-loop. The loop body is executed once for each file name found in the current directory.

The array actually consists of a set of variables all starting with `file` and with a number appended (like `file1`, `file2`. The number is stored in the variable `index` and is incremented in each loop iteration. In the loop body that number and the corresponding file name are also printed out

In the next part the `SET /P` command asks the user to enter a number which is then stored in the variable `selection`. The second `SET` command and the following `IF` are used to check if the entered number will give a valid array index by checking for a `fileX` variable.

Finally the `RESOLVE` subroutine is used to copy the content of the variable formed by `file` + the entered number in `selection` to a variable named `file_name` that can then be used for further processing.

Hope that gives some hints.

Comment: This is a great script for selecting Files.  However someone might need to list or select folders (directories), in that case just make this change.  Before: `FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
`  After: `FOR /F %%f IN ('dir /b /ad') DO (`

Comment: Great job Frank! Can you do it also with multiple selection? 1,3 or 2,5 or maybe all options together